# `rake notes` should scan haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, ruby-on-rails-4.2

According to the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/command_line.html#notes):

> ...  is done in files with extension .builder, .rb, .erb, .haml and .slim for both default and custom annotations.

But it isn't working, even when manually configured:

```
$ rails -v
  Rails 4.2.3
$ grep -r annotations config/environments/development.rb
  config/environments/development.rb:  config.annotations.register_extensions('haml') { |a| /#\s*(#{a}):?\s*(.*)$/ }
$ grep -r TODO app/views
  app/views/orders/show.html.haml:  -# TODO: Add link
$ rake notes
  app/models/order.rb:
    * [12] [TODO] Refactor
```

Anyone know how to get it working?

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**

Add this line

```
SourceAnnotationExtractor::Annotation.register_extensions("haml") { |tag| /(?:\/\/|#)\s*(#{tag}):?\s*(.*)$/ }
```

at the end of Rakefile inside of your Rails app.

**Longer answer**

```
rake notes
```

is defined there :
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks/annotations.rake

```
task :notes do
  SourceAnnotationExtractor.enumerate "OPTIMIZE|FIXME|TODO", tag: true
end
```

this task doesn't depend on :environment, so for example, no code inside config/initializers/ or config/environment will be executed for this task. Putting any configuration there won't have any effect for rake notes.

Only config/application.rb will be required, from Rakefile.
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/source_annotation_extractor.rb tells us that we can define a new file extension for Annotations like this :

```
SourceAnnotationExtractor::Annotation.register_extensions("css", "scss", "sass", "less", "js") { |tag| /\/\/\s*(#{tag}):?\s*(.*)$/ }
```

so adding this line inside Rakefile or config/application.rb will define the new annotation before the notes task is executed.

I'm not sure why it doesn't work out of the box for haml, since it's defined in haml-rails.
For the time being, with Rails 4.2.2 and haml-rails 0.9.0, the short answer above should do.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following into `config/initializers/` :

```
Rails.application.config.annotations.tap do |notes|
  notes.register_extensions('haml') { |annotation| %r(#\s*(#{annotation}):?\s*(.*?)$) }
end
```

for more details you can refer [this](http://makandracards.com/makandra/32263-make-rake-notes-learn-about-haml-sass-coffeescript-and-other-file-types)

Comment: That's equivalent to my `config.annotations.register_extensions('haml') { |a| /#\s*(#{a}):?\s*(.*)$/ }`. I tried it, just in case, but it didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Zubin have you checked the url?

Comment: Yes I've seen that page.